# How to loop until no IE process is running

Tags: powershell

```
# Close all IE and tabs
(New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application').Windows() | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -like '*Internet Explorer*'
} | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Quit()
    [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($_)
}

[GC]::Collect()
[GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: `while(Get-Process iexplore){ <# your existing script goes here #> }`

Answer (score 1):

As Mr. Mathias commented, you can use a while loop. You can also use an until loop

```
do
{
    your code here..
}
until( -not (Get-Process iexplore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
```

or

```
do
{
    your code here..
}
until((Get-Process iexplore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).count -eq 0)
```

or

```
do
{
    your code here..
}
until($null -eq (Get-Process iexplore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
```